# Is there any way to program using Objective C on Ubuntu?

Tags: ide, objective-c

Is there a IDE, library that could allow me to code Objective C on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu includes GCC's Objective C compiler in the `gobjc` package. So you can compile your programs via `gcc` and debug using `gdb`.

`gedit` support objective C syntax highlighting.

If you want an IDE like `xcode` with apple sdk, framework. Then the answer is no. It is not possible.

Comment: "If you want an IDE like xcode with apple sdk, framework. Then the answer is no."

Or "yes", [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org) is available from Ubuntu Software Center and contains the ProjectCenter IDE.